# Como subir api restFul de node

Tags: nodejs, api, hosting

Tengo dessarrollada una api restFull en node para un cliente y la iba a subir a heroku pero me he encontrado con que no funciona, alguien sabe alguna alternativa es mi primera vez subiendo algo al servidor y no se como hacerlo.

Comment: Qué significa No funciona? Por qué dices que no funciona? Algún log que puedas compartir cuando la pruebas en el entorno en el que no funciona?

Comment: no se me sale como que todo ha ido bien pero despues la pagina no carga y al ejecutar herokulog --tail me sale esto:

Comment: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-09-03T11:35:58.012259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

Comment: mi codigo de arranque del servidor es este

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = require('./app')
var port = process.env.PROT || 5800

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://zehcnas:yaizan2020@cluster0.5mlxv.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useNewUrlParser: true })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('conexion a la vase de datos establecida')
            //creacion del server

            app.listen(port, () => {
                console.log('server arrancado en el puerto ' + port)
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que todo esto se ve más fácil, mejor y lo puedes formatear si editas la pregunta. Usa el enlace editar que esta justo debajo de tu pregunta.